# The Folding Maze

Tags: mazes, paper-folding

Four years ago, I drew a really nice maze.  I have recreated it with the wonders of MS Paint for all of you to enjoy.

Just begin at the green START, exit by the red arrow, and don't pass through black lines.

[image: A-maze-ing!]

Here's the gimmick:  You are allowed to fold the paper.  The maze is creased at four lines:  Mountain folds along the orange lines, and valley folds along the blue lines.

To transform the maze, you can do one of three things:

- Mountain fold across the orange horizontal line, and then valley fold across the blue horizontal line.
- Mountain fold along the orange vertical line, and then valley fold along the blue vertical line.
- Unfold everything.

Each fold will bring an orange line to the corresponding green line, which acts as a nice guideline.  Cool, right?

Although you can probably solve it by just staring at the given picture, I think it's fun if you print it.  You can print this pdf:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7er3zsqhtjnw9rg/Folding%20Maze.pdf?dl=0

Or, if you don't trust strangers on the internet, you can simply download the given picture and then print it.

If you do plan on printing it, here are my recommended steps for maximum folding precision:

1. First, mountain fold along the horizontal orange line.  Crease sharply.
2. Now, take the edge of the fold, which is the orange line, and bring it up and over to overlap with the green line.  Crease.  You will know you've found the right alignment when the lines line up.  Ignore the blue line as a guideline, it is too hard to use.
3. Repeat for the vertical creases.

That's all.  Have fun!

Comment: woah this looks really cool

Comment: Wow this is really nice

Comment: looks cool, but on your second bullet point did you mean to put mountain fold on a blue line? i feel like that should be valley fold on a blue line as blue lines represent valley folds

Comment: Ah whoops, fixed.

Comment: For those who enjoyed this, Friedemann Frise, the notable board game designer, created a series of folding mazes: https://boardgamegeekstore.com/products/friedemann-frieses-folders.

Comment: What happens when I fold while standing between the orange and green line? Can I also have both directions folded?

Comment: If you fold between the folds, I guess the guy in the maze gets squished (yeah nothing special happens). Having both directions folded is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

My Answer:

Red lines are where you would go, yellow lines indicate moving over the fold.

> [image]

Comment: Nice!  You got it.

Comment: Great Job @Austin Weaver!

Comment: How did you dare to soil that beautiful piece of MS Paint art? +1 anyway

Comment: @xhienne only with my own beautiful MS Paint artistry :)

Comment: @xhienne I hope [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63754/12114) is a less "soil"-y version. :P (@Austin) Feel free to edit it in, then I will delete my submission. :)

Answer (score 25):

Well, you beat me by 30 minutes, but I worked hard on this so I'm posting it anyway :)

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

> [image]

<s>Ever-so-slightly different than the others</s> Looks like this is actually the same as Austin Weaver's path... Remember to pay attention to the pixels, they matter!

Comment: Could you please point out the difference between yours and Austin Weaver's path ?

Comment: @Saeïdryl Ah, it looks like it's the same as his, but different from Selvek's (thought it was different from both users' paths at first). I'll edit that in. I will keep this here though, just in case somebody can't exactly read Austin's image.

Comment: Definitely less "soily" :-)